# Unable to execute billing on LG Nexus 5X

Tags: android, in-app-billing, billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

My app has in-app purchases. I use the billing library:

```
def billing_version = "4.1.0"
implementation("com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version")
implementation("com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:$billing_version")
```

I observe in Firebase, that **user with LG Nexus 5X (Android 8.1) can't make the purchase. He tried several times, but gets the same problem**:

[image: fatal exception]

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{studio.yatoo.calendarwidget/com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.IntentSender android.app.PendingIntent.getIntentSender()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11()
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.IntentSender android.app.PendingIntent.getIntentSender()' on a null object reference
   at com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity.onCreate(com.android.billingclient:billing@@4.1.0:11)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11()
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**All other users have no such problem. Only user with LG Nexus 5X. Could somebody help, how to solve this problem?**

Comment: I have no answer to this, but I too have a mystery Nexus 5X holdout that is apparently getting the same error (or at least I'm getting the crash report). Is this device still popular? I seem to see it unusually often in my logs. Something seems a bit fishy. **EDIT** See this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200437477). Looks like my suspicion was correct.

Comment: @technicalflaw Thank you for your comment. I observe regularly that somebody with this Nexus 5X tries to buy my app, but can't do this because of this crash. Nobody else has such a problem. I've looked through a lot of forums regarding the issue with Nexus 5X... There is a question, but nobody has an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in my comment below the question, I get the feeling this is safe to ignore. My app is relatively niche, and the probability of someone with a device this old, with this OS version, making a purchase so soon is almost zero. I wish Google would be more explicit about their automated testing devices, as I've wasted time chasing similar, seemingly impossible bugs before, but this smells like it's safe to ignore (with caution).

Comment: I agree with you. I have repeatedly encountered situations where I spent many days solving problems, which, as it turned out later, were not on my side, but on the side of either Google or the manufacturer of the smartphone. Now I've decided to ignore the problem with Nexus 5X